# Can't add another script in bash

Tags: bash, scripting

I wrote a bash script which calls another script in the same folder. I am doing this by simply putting `./email_pacotes.sh` in the main script

```
#awk '{print $2}' >> /tmp/lista_pacotes.log adiciona resultado ao arquivo /tmp/tmp_pacotes_adicionados.log
echo "\nPacotes adicionados até" $(date) "\n" >> /tmp/tmp_pacotes_adicionados.log

cat /tmp/diferencas.log >> /tmp/tmp_pacotes_adicionados.log

./email_pacotes.sh

#adiciona resultados anteriores
cat /tmp/pacotes_adicionados.log >> /tmp/tmp_pacotes_adicionados.log
```

I thought that it was working correctly, but I had to debug the script for other reasons and I found out it wasn't adding the second script the first time a run the main script.

I was getting the following message:

```
[...]
./email_pacotes.sh: 17: ./email_pacotes.sh: [[: not found
./email_pacotes.sh: 17: ./email_pacotes.sh: [[: not found
./email_pacotes.sh: 17: ./email_pacotes.sh: [[: not found
./email_pacotes.sh: 17: ./email_pacotes.sh: [[: not found
./email_pacotes.sh: 17: ./email_pacotes.sh: [[: not found
[...]
```

This happens when I run the script the first time I put it in a folder. If I run it again, the message doesn't show anymore, so I guessing it is not a problem with the syntax. I also thought could be something with permissions, but I changed both scripts to 0777 and the message persists.

Is this a normal behaviour? What could be causing this?

Obs1: I am debugging the main script using the -x option.

Obs2: I made another test now. It keeps throwing the same message, but at certain point it finally calls the script. So maybe is just the time to find the file or throw a exception?

Comment: Could it be a bit of syntax that doesn't get run first time due to a conditional?  It's impossible to say if you don't post the relevant part of the script.

Comment: @martinclayton The script is really big, but there is no condition at all. This command is completely unrelated to anything.

Comment: Suggest you extract lines 12-22 and post, so that potential answerers can at least see line 17 in context.

Comment: @mrfred Actually, I started with the absolute path then moved to relative. Both throw the error.

Comment: Are you really writing bash scripts, or is your shebang `#!/bin/sh`?  When run as `sh`, bash is in "POSIX compatibility mode" and bash extensions like `[[` may not be available. Or, depending on your OS, `/bin/sh` may not even *be* bash. The best way to get community help, though would be for you to construct an [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can reproduce the problem itself, and to provide full details about the environment you're running this in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error, I'm pretty sure you're running the second script with a shell other than bash. The `[[ ]]` conditional is supported by bash (and zsh and maybe some other shells), but is not standard and there are other shells that don't support it. So if you want to use that (or any other nonstandard bash features), you need to use a proper shebang line in that script. Generally, that means you need to start the script with `#!/bin/bash` (or maybe `#!/usr/bin/env bash`), **not** with `#!/bin/sh`.

There's another thing that worries me, though. Running the second script with `./email_pacotes.sh` will look for it in the current working directory, which is inherited from the process that ran the first script, and could be pretty much anywhere. If you want it to look for the second script in the same directory the first script is in, the best way is to locate the first script with something like `"$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")"` (and guess what -- `BASH_SOURCE` is a bash-only feature, so start the first script with a bash shebang as well). Then you can either refer to the second script (and any other relevant files) by explicit path:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
scriptDir="$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")"
if [[ ! -d "$scriptDir" ]]; then
    echo "Something's terribly wrong; I can't find myself!" >&2
    exit 1
fi
...
"$scriptDir/email_pacotes.sh"
```

or have the script `cd` to its own directory and then use relative paths:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
cd "$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")" || {
    echo "Something's terribly wrong; I can't cd to my own directory!" >&2
    exit 1
}
...
./email_pacotes.sh
```

I prefer the first approach, because if the any of the scripts accepts paths (e.g. as arguments), the user will expect those paths to be interpreted relative to where the user was when they ran the script, not relative to where the script itself is; `cd`ing in the script will break this.

Comment: I am using bash. I started with #!/bin/bash. As I said, the script is very big, so I didn't post it completely. I am going to try the first approach you mentioned.

Comment: @EGS Not being able to find the second script shouldn't give the error message you're seeing -- unless you have *another* script named email_pacotes.sh in some other directory that doesn't have the proper shebang and it's finding that one instead. This might explain why it sometimes just starts working: at some point you cd to the directory the scripts are in, and suddenly it's finding the right version of the second script.